# Splitting a File into Chunks with Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, chunking

I'm trying to take a single file object and split it into chunks by a specified chunk size.
In my example, trying to split a single file into 1MB chunks. So I figure out how many chunks it would take, then I'm trying to slice the file starting from the 'offset' (current chunk I'm on * chunk size), and slicing off a chunk size.
My first slice comes out properly at 1MB but my subsequent slices turn out to 0, any ideas why?
Have a working codepen here:

http://codepen.io/ngalluzzo/pen/VvpYKz?editors=001[1]

```
var file = $('#uploadFile')[0].files[0];
  var chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;
  var fileSize = file.size;
  var chunks = Math.ceil(file.size/chunkSize,chunkSize);
  var chunk = 0;

  console.log('file size..',fileSize);
  console.log('chunks...',chunks);

  while (chunk <= chunks) {
      var offset = chunk*chunkSize;
      console.log('current chunk..', chunk);
      console.log('offset...', chunk*chunkSize);
      console.log('file blob from offset...', offset)
      console.log(file.slice(offset,chunkSize));
      chunk++;
  }
```

Comment: Your codepen seems to be working for me.  One difference between your codepen and the code above is that your codepen correctly says: `file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize)` instead of `file.slice(offset, chunkSize)`.  Also you're producing an empty blob at the end, because your while condition should be `while (chunk < chunks)`.

Comment: Yeah I updated the codepen with the solution below, working great. Thanks for looking!

Comment: And Math.ceil only take one parameter: `var chunks = Math.ceil(file.size/chunkSize);`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Was slicing off the wrong ends:

```
console.log(file.slice(offset,chunkSize));
```

should have been

```
console.log(file.slice(offset,offset+chunkSize));
```

Answer (score 7):

Use The function below to split a big file into multiple chunks. I have used it with react, it's works.

```
  createChunks = (file,cSize/* cSize should be byte 1024*1 = 1KB */) => {
   let startPointer = 0;
   let endPointer = file.size;
   let chunks = [];
   while(startPointer<endPointer){
    let newStartPointer = startPointer+cSize;
    chunks.push(file.slice(startPointer,newStartPointer));
    startPointer = newStartPointer;
   }
   return chunks;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Fuad, am currently facing the issue of uploading large files, please can you throw more light on how I can split big file into multiple and upload to an endpoint that accept chunks upload

Comment: wow very clean solution good day sir :)

Comment: Will this actually work if there are _hundreds of thousands_ or even _millions_ of 1kB chunks? It's hard to fathom that a contemporary browser would accommodate JS trying to allocate so much dynamic/heap memory at once?

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting what was above, I write expanded, dir in folder named "in" and then split, cut files and name them by increasing number of files, it will output in "out" folder, name.z00, name.z01, name.z02...

```
const fs = require('fs')

function numberName (numberFile,index){
    if(numberFile<10){
        return "0"+index
    }
    if(numberFile<100){
        if(index<10)
            return "00"+index
        return "0"+index
    }
}

var createChunks = (file,cSize/* cSize should be byte 1024*1 = 1KB */) => {
    let startPointer = 0;
    let endPointer = file.length;
    let chunks = [];
    while(startPointer<endPointer){
    let newStartPointer = startPointer+cSize;
    chunks.push(file.slice(startPointer,newStartPointer));
    startPointer = newStartPointer;
    }
    return chunks;
}
function splitDirFile(cSize){
    var list = fs.readdirSync("./in");
    console.log(list)
    list.map(fileName=>{
        var chunks = createChunks(fs.readFileSync("./in/"+fileName),cSize)
        //console.log(list.length);
        var name = fileName.slice(0,fileName.length-4)
        chunks.map((buff,i)=>{
            fs.writeFileSync("./out/"+name+".z"+numberName(chunks.length,i),buff)
        })
    })

}

splitDirFile(1024*1024*10)
```