# AJAX/PHP - Upload a large file in segments in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, upload, segment

I'm trying to let users upload huge files ~1GB using PHP and HTML/JS.
I know from past experiences that uploading files ~10mb also causes PHP to refuse the request.

Issue is, the request in my js gets sent, but I can't figure out how to send blobs through php. the post request is always empty

My javascript goes like this:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
function doThing(){
      var file = document.getElementById("file_upload").files[0];
      var chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;
      var fileSize = file.size;
      var chunks = Math.ceil(file.size/chunkSize,chunkSize);
      var chunk = 0;

      console.log('file size..',fileSize);
      console.log('chunks...',chunks);
      sendFileSlice(file, chunkSize, chunk, chunks); 
}

function sendFileSlice(file, chunkSize, chunk, chunks)
{
      if(chunk <= chunks)
      {
          var offset = chunk*chunkSize;
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             chunk++;
             sendFileSlice(file, chunkSize, chunk, chunks);
            }
          };
          xhttp.open("POST", "printchunks.php", true);
          xhttp.send(file.slice(offset,offset+chunkSize));
      }
}
```

and my php, just for test, goes like this:

```
<?php
//temporarily just put contents into a random file
file_put_contents(time()+rand(), print_r($_POST, true));
?>
```

I'm using [Splitting a File into Chunks with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898082/splitting-a-file-into-chunks-with-javascript) this as an example for splitting, but i can't find AJAX using pure Javascript. I do NOT want JQuery, that's the last thing I need, I just want to send a blob to PHP so it can append it to the file. This seems to work in terms of splitting, it just doesn't have anything in the files produced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot that I had to use

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
```

before sending to set the stream to be a blob. With this, I can now save the file using this PHP:

```
<?php
file_put_contents(time()+rand(), file_get_contents("php://input"));
?>
```

Of course this saves it into some random file, so if this helps anyone, please change the code to fit your needs