# How to slice a file into chunks in react-native

Tags: react-native, file, chunks, react-native-fs, react-native-fetch-blob

```
ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
  createChunks(response);
});
```

I got file uri,path from imagepicker, i want to divide the file into chunks and upload as form data,How to divide the media file(mp4,etc) into chunks in react-native.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898082/splitting-a-file-into-chunks-with-javascript

Comment: Hi did you get the answer to your question? I am also stuck here..

Comment: I tweaked this library to implement this feature.I don't remember the exact steps https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-chunk-upload